# How can store a datagridview as a array in a cell of a mysql table

Tags: vb.net

I want to store the content of a DataGridView in a array
and the other way round I want to read a array into a Datagridview.

I found this class on the net

```
Public Class Loads
    Private L_nr As String
    Private L_plz As String
    Private L_km As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal nr, ByVal plz, ByVal km)
        L_nr = nr
        L_plz = plz
        L_km = km
    End Sub
    Public Property nr() As String
        Get
            Return L_nr
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            L_nr = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property plz() As String
        Get
            Return L_plz
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            L_plz = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property km() As String
        Get
            Return L_km
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            L_km = Value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I xan use it like this

```
Private Sub DataGridViewLoads1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)        Handles DataGridViewLoads1.Click

    Dim al As New Collections.ArrayList()
    al.Add(New Loads(123, 234, 1971))
    DataGridViewLoads1.DataSource = al

End Sub
```

But its not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use collection of class instances for displaying and editing data in `DataGridView`

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

Create collection and show it in `DataGridView`

```
Dim persons = new List(Of Person) From
{
    New Person { .Id = 1, .Name = "One" },
    New Person { .Id = 2, .Name = "Two" },
    New Person { .Id = 3, .Name = "Three" }
}

yourDataGridView.DataSource = persons
```

When you want save all data from `DataGridView` use same instance of `persons` or cast it from `.DataSource`

```
Dim dataToSave = DirectCast(yourDataGridView.DataSource, List(Of Person))
```

Then serialize data to string in `json` format for example(feel free to use any other format)

```
Dim serializedData AS String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToSave)
```

Then save that string in database.

For displaying data from database:

```
// retrieve value from database
Dim serializedData As String = GetFromDatabaseYourFunction()
Dim data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Person))(serializedData)
yourDataGridView.DataSource = data
```